# Tiling a polygon into relatively even squares?

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector-grid, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a polygon that I would like to cut into even tiles that are around 100 x 100 m  (it doesn't have to be perfect). I found the ee.Geometry.Polygon.cutLines() method, but when I use it nothing shows up in the Earth Engine map layer. Even using the example provided on the Earth Engine developers website (link [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-polygon-cutlines)) does not show anything on the map layer.

Am I missing something here or is this not the right method to use?

I'm also providing my code below.

```
var bbox = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-124.45631095733451, 32.27807045552821],
          [-114.08521720733451, 32.27807045552821],
          [-114.08521720733451, 42.09026838316091],
          [-124.45631095733451, 42.09026838316091]]]);
var polygonCutLines = bbox.cutLines({"distances": [100, 100], 'maxError': 1});
Map.addLayer(polygonCutLines)
print(polygonCutLines)
```

Comment: "Even" tiles in decimal degrees won't *look* even, and if they do look even, they aren't.

Comment: That's alright. It doesn't need to be even. I just need a way to cut down a polygon by 100 x100 squares. It doesn't have to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the coveringGrid() method to split up the polygon into tiles of 100 meter resolution. But this might not be what you want - if your use case is better fitted to the raster space, you might run into issues working with a FeatureCollection of that size, so if you're able to express the operation in ee.Image() space you might find that that scales better.